# Google map crashing on Android 10

Tags: android, google-maps, android-native-library

I have implemented Google maps on android, that is working fine till Android Pie.
But on 10, I am getting the following crash.

```
com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.util.jni.zza: Exception while extracting native library.
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.util.jni.NativeHelper.safeLoadLibrary(NativeHelper.java:53)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.util.jni.NativeHelper.ensureLibraryLoaded(NativeHelper.java:17)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.diskcache.NativeSqliteDiskCacheImpl.<clinit>(NativeSqliteDiskCacheImpl.java:141)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.diskcache.NativeSqliteDiskCacheImpl.createOrOpenDatabase(NativeSqliteDiskCacheImpl.java:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.diskcache.zzf.zza(SqliteDiskCache.java:6)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.diskcache.zzg.zzc(SqliteDiskCacheProvider.java:104)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.diskcache.zzg.zza(SqliteDiskCacheProvider.java:31)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.zzbe.zza(TileStoreFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.map.internal.store.zzbe.zza(TileStoreFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.bl.zzex.zza(TileOverlayFactory.java:56)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.bl.zzdq.zza(PhoenixGoogleMapActivityEnvironment.java:127)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.bl.zzdq.zzd(PhoenixGoogleMapActivityEnvironment.java:210)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.av.zzg.zza(MapContainer.java:26)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.gu.zzat.zza(RendererFactoryImpl.java:177)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzav.zza(GoogleMapImpl.java:59)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzci.zza(MapFragmentDelegateImpl.java:3)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzcg.zza(MapFragmentDelegateImpl.java:15)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(SupportMapFragment.java:15)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zae.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:25)
    at com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(SupportMapFragment.java:34)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:851)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:239)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
```

If any other details are required, I will be happy to oblige. 
Any help or hint on the matter is very much appreciated.

**Edit- Code part**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync {
            map = it
            it.setLocationSource(LocationSource)
        }

    }
```

Layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            class="com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </fragment>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_loc_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

**Work-around**
After numerous trials and error, found the error to be the build tools version
Changing `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` 
fixed it.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail which code you wrote

Comment: @KintanPatel I have added relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your XML with below code,

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--Change start-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </FrameLayout>
<!--        Change end-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_loc_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Your you fragment Coding Part,

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

            val smf = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, smf).commit()
            smf.getMapAsync({
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Map Ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        }
```

Enjoy your day.

Comment: you are making some mistake,try to make new project and select map activity.

Comment: Your's is running on android 10? Can you also mention your play services version? Because it was working with 3.x.x but not with 4.3.2

Comment: implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'